# Get-CsUser error powershell

Tags: powershell, office365, skype-for-business

I am running this command in powershell   `Get-CsUser` and i am getting the following error

```
Get-CsUser : The term 'Get-CsUser' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
+ Get-CsUser
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-CsUser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What do I have to do to avoid this error? I have imported:

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Skype for Business Online\Modules\SkypeOnlineConnector\SkypeOnlineConnector.psd1"
```

and then made connection to Office 365 Skype for business service with the following script:

```
$credential = Get-Credential
Import-Module MSOnline
Connect-MsolService -Credential $credential
Import-Module SkypeOnlineConnector
$lyncSession = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $credential
Import-PSSession $lyncSession
```

Does anyone knows what's the cause of this error?

Comment: import the `.psm1` file, not the `.psd1`

Comment: @cet51 That's not the problem.  OP: I don't see you using `Get-CsUser` anywhere in your code example.

Comment: @cet51 Yes, it'll search the folder for a module manifest of the same name (which is how module loading in general works, it looks at the psd1 file to tell it what to do).  There aren't enough details in this question to tell what's wrong, though.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone knows what s the cause of this error? thank you in advance

Problem is office 365 skype for business **does not** have a command "**Get-CsUser**" under User cmdlets.

Available User cmdlets are as follows.

```
Set-CsUser

Get-CsUserPstnSettings

Set-CsUserPstnSettings

Get-CsUserSession
```

Source "[Skype for Business Online cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228132.aspx)"

**Get-CsUser** is available for on-premises lync servers.
.

**PS:**
Your connection for  "office 365 skype for business" and  the session import should be ok, for example if you type Get-CsUserSession, it **should not** say "The term 'Get-CsUserSession' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"

(1) You can view **available** commands in your **imported module** using below

```
Get-Command -Module MSOnline
Get-Command -Module SkypeOnlineConnector
```

(2) You can also view available commands in **your current session** by using Get-Command and your temporary session name.

```
Get-Command -Module tmp_aqu5qmxt.frb
```

tmp_aqu5qmxt.frb is my temperory session id name .. change it to whatever you get at this screen.

[image]

(3) To view **all imported commands** from all your sources, (modules+sessions) you can use,

```
Get-Command -ListImported
```

None of them has a command called **"Get-CsUser"**

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer.
What I would like to do is to get the list of users of Office 365 Skype for Business:
I used your commands for better understanding (i am very new to PowerShell) and then searched a little bit more on the internet and came across to this command: `Get-Msoluser`, maybe I can use this one. If you have any other suggestion please do. Thank you again.

Comment: if it is about skype for business users , user Get-CsOnlineUser instead of  Get-Msoluser . examples > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/get-csonlineuser?view=skype-ps

Comment: see also https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sfb/get-csonlineuser-returnning-all-users/2008cc5f-e8c0-4d07-9a7a-1b3f134ed1b3

Answer (score 0):

**In Skype for Business Online you should use `Get-CsOnlineUser` instead of `Get-CsUser`**.

As stated in the [documentation os Get-CsUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/Get-CsUser?view=skype-ps) it's not available for Skype for Business Online.

If you use `Get-Command Get-Cs*User` you'll find only the following 3 commands:

> Get-CsOnlineDialInConferencingUser
>
> ### Get-CsOnlineUser
>
> Get-CsOnlineVoiceUser

The second one is the one you should use to display users homed online. I already requested a change to MS documentation to include that as a hint, hopefully they you'll accept that.